# HAML table data radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to have something like this work:

```
    - @ordered_articles.each do |x|
  %tr
    %td= x.short_title
    %td= x.label.nil? ? '' : x.label.title
    %td= published_at(x)
    %td= last_update(x)
    %td= x.radio_button :checked =>"false"
```

but I get the error: undefined method radio_button

Any idea how I could possibly get this to work?

Comment: You'll have to use the rails form helpers to do this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting form inputs inside table element will usually lead to errors.

My advice would be to either use `div`s instead of a table, or put individual forms inside of each of the `td` elements.

for example:

```
%td
  = form_for @something, html: {id: "radio-form" } do |f|
    = f.radio_button :checked =>"false"
    = f.submit style: 'display: none;'
```

then add some javascript to submit on change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#radio-form input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    $(#radio-form").trigger("submit.rails");
  });
});
```

Comment: `div` or `td` is not really the question here. There is nothing wrong with having form elements inside a table. It might offend some purists, but it's not wrong in any way.